# Still shows as pending in etherscan but Transaction dropped and replaced

Tags: transactions, pending-transactions

I Replaced a transaction by sending  transaction  customizing the nonce in Metamask. Now the Replaced transaction shows as "dropped & replaced" in etherscan, but it's still pending:

https://etherscan.io/tx/0xfa3e403378a177269e5254af9d9e5dc390b74167367fabf67e59cb12f635ad5b

https://etherscan.io/address/0x04bb04603d8c44c6f0be772db6aa0681ca55ffea

If I try to send a transaction with a higher nonce it will not pass through as there is a pending transaction with a lower nonce.

So basically my wallet is stuck. Is there something I can do about it?

Comment: solved the problem by resetting Metamask